# JScrollpane: Add element when scroll to bottom

Tags: jquery, jscrollpane

I have applied JScrollpane to a `<ul> <li>`.Now I need to add more `<li>` when scroll to bottom of that `<ul>` through ajax.

Any idea?

TIA
Jaya

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the 'jsp-scroll-y' event. This event is triggered when the user scrolls the y bar. More info on the event [here](http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/events.html). Since browsers trigger this event more than once each time, instead of using jQuery's normal .bind or .on, I use jQuery debounce plugin to prevent browsers from firing the function more than once every 200ms. You can download JQuery debounce [here](https://github.com/diaspora/jquery-debounce). So let's say your structure is like this:

```
<div id="container">
  <ul id="list">
    <li> ... </li>
    <li> ... </li>
    <li> ... </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

The javascript to achieve your goal using JQuery would look like:

```
var container = $('#container');
var list = $('#list');

// initialize the scroll pane
container.jScrollPane();

// bind the event
container.debounce('jsp-scroll-y', function(event, scrollPositionY, isAtTop, isAtBottom) {
    if (isAtBottom) {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            async: true,
            dataType: 'html',
            url: '/path/to/more/elements',
            success: function(data) {
                if (data.length) {
                    list.append(data);
                    container.jScrollPane('reinitialise');
                } else {
                    container.unbind('jsp-scroll-y');
                }
            },
        });
    }
}, 200);
```

Of course, in this scenario, '/path/to/more/elements' should return li elements, and nothing when you are done receiving everything. I use a page index that I increment in the AJAX success function to get new elements. You get send this page index to the server using data in the ajax calls or in the URL (it depends of the implementation on the server).